# Need help getting all the occurrences of a given table - Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

so lets say i have these tables:

```
Students
--------
code_student (pk)
name
address

Teacher
--------
code_teacher (pk)
name
address

Class
---------
code_class (pk)
description


History
----------
code_student    (pk)(fk)
code_class      (pk)(fk)
code_teacher    (pk)(fk)
year
grade
```

And i want the students who attended all the classes of a given professor. I have been using this approach:

```
select code_student,name 
from    student s   
where not   EXISTS  (
            select  code_teacher
            from    teacher t
            where   t.name  like    'John Smith' AND    not EXISTS  (
                                            select  code_teacher
                                            from    history h
                                            where   t.code_teacher  =   h.code_teacher 
                                            and s.code_student = h.code_student));
```

used by my teacher (double nested query with not exists) but i cant seem to figure it out properly. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing it, this is more expandable in that it allows you to get results for multiple teachers at a time and will find for each teacher all of the students that have taken all of their classes.

You're just looking to see that the number of unique classes that a student has taken with a teacher matches the number of unique classes that the teacher has offered. Personally, I find this method a little clearer as well. The `DISTINCT` on the counts is necessary to account for the teacher offering the same class in multiple years and/or a student taking the same class more than once.

```
SELECT
    S.code_student,
    S.name AS student_name,
    T.code_teacher,
    T.name AS teacher_name
FROM
    Student S
INNER JOIN Teacher T ON T.name = 'John Smith'
INNER JOIN History H ON
    H.code_student = S.code_student AND
    H.code_teacher = T.code_teacher
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT code_teacher, COUNT(DISTINCT code_class) AS cnt
    FROM History
    GROUP BY code_teacher
) SQ ON
    SQ.code_teacher = T.code_teacher
GROUP BY
    S.code_student,
    S.name AS student_name,
    T.code_teacher,
    T.name AS teacher_name,
    SQ.cnt
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT H.code_class) = SQ.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Oracle database?  You can do it without subqueries by using analytic functions.

```
SELECT distinct student_name, teacher_name FROM
(
    SELECT  s.name student_name, 
            t.name teacher_name, 
            count(DISTINCT h.code_class) OVER ( PARTITION BY h.code_teacher ) classes_taught_by_teacher,
            count(DISTINCT h.code_class) OVER ( PARTITION BY h.code_teacher, h.code_student ) teacher_classes_taken_by_stu 
    FROM    history h
    INNER JOIN students s ON s.code_student = h.code_student
    INNER JOIN teacher t on t.code_teacher = h.code_teacher
    WHERE t.name = 'John Smith' )
WHERE  teacher_class_taken_by_stu = classes_taught_by_teacher
```